# What to call the best student in a class?

Tags: single-word-requests, nonsubjective

Is there a word in English to qualify the highest-ranked student in a class in a year?

We are talking here about higher education, especially in the context of curricula that keep a given set of students over the course of several years, being ranked at the end of each year, possibly with competitive admission for the following year. The ranking is a weighted average of all marks obtained over the year.

I am looking for a single word, or expression, to quickly designate the one student with the highest ranking. If there is no such thing in English, then let's try to get the most concise and idiomatic definition.

In all cases, it is *not* emotionally connoted, i.e. not pejorative nor bragging.

*For French speakers: I am looking for the translation of **“major de promotion”**.*

---

**EDIT**: additional, not as much of a pure “word request” question: is this anything you should mention on a curriculum vitæ in the English-speaking world? If so, please mention whether the given word is appropriate for such a use  :)

Comment: I'd say that pointing out that you are the top student is bragging no matter what word you use, but maybe that's just me being overly sensitive :P

Comment: When I was growing up, the best student in the class was called a swot.... though it was derogatory. Not sure where it came from though

Comment: @Supr Well, we're talking about a resume. I don't find it any more bragging than any other achievement. It is not the same as bringing it randomly in a conversation. I guess there's also a cultural thing in here, which is why I asked whether it was appropriate in the English-speaking world. This is definitely something you should mention on a French resume, along with your rank and honors.

Comment: @MattiSG Oh don't get me wrong, I'm not saying you shouldn't mention it :) There's not necessarily anything wrong with bragging, sometimes it's appropriate, especially on your resume -- that's what it's for ;)

Comment: In a given subject area, but usually not a student, the term could be [doyen](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/doyen?view=uk) meaning the most respected or prominent person in a particular field

Comment: close General Reference. -1 research not shown.

Comment: @ΜετάEd Huh? What's the matter?

Comment: Please include research results, meaning what references you consulted before asking here, what they said, etc. See the [faq] and the article it links to about asking a good question. General Reference means a question that is answerable right out of a dictionary, thesaurus, or other reference work.

Comment: @ΜετάEd I tried Google, and all terms lookup always end up finding tutorials for [being the top student](http://www.google.com/search?q=top%20student%20of%20a%20class&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). This question is not answerable out of a dictionary nor a thesaurus: which word would you look up? Please define the other reference work I should have consulted.

Comment: A Google search [ define major de promotion ] brought up several likely choices. You could confirm those in a dictionary or thesaurus. Even if you turned up nothing, it is basic site etiquette to show what you tried so we do not duplicate your effort.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Valedictorian, but this is an American expression.

Comment: It looks like you're [right](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/spellcheck/british/?q=valedictorian), but I had no idea this term was [American](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/valedictorian). Very interesting.

Comment: Interesting definition (_“delivers valedictory […]”_). By “American expression”, do you mean it will be understood only in the US, or that the ceremony it refers to is US-centric, but for lack of a better word this is accepted usage for all English speakers?

Comment: Yes, it's mostly used in the USA. Even if you check Wiki for this info, it will be stated there. What to say about other more trustfull sources.

Comment: As for the usage - it refers to American reality, but probably this word will be also understood by British speakers. But you not better use it in some official papers in Great Britain.

Comment: I'm British. I've never heard of it.

Comment: Andrew, is there British equivalent?

Comment: @Andrew: Just for the record, it's a very well-known term in the U.S., not obscure whatsoever. (Traditionally, the valedictorian gives a speech at high school commencement ceremonies.) And, in accordance with what the O.P. is asking for, it's considered neither pejorative nor braggadocio; it's a neutral term that could be inserted into a CV just fine – at least a CV for American eyes.

Comment: @J.R.: I think that should be resume.

Comment: I'm also British, and never heard it in Britain. It is definitely very US-centric. I would just say 'top of that class' or similar.

Comment: @Tim: Agreed (on _resume_ vs. _CV_). Nice catch.

Comment: And *salutatorian* for the second-best, although this is less well-known.

Comment: Are these terms still used if this tradition was not actually kept (i.e. the person was not actually invited to - or did not actually - give a speech at the commencement ceremony)?

Comment: Are you all sure it is US-centric, and not only academic-centric? The original French saying I gave is not well known by the general public, but it is definitely known by anyone involved in higher studies that have ranking systems.

Comment: @Random832 It's still tradition where I went to high school for the Valedictorian (and salutatorian) to give a speech at commencement.

Comment: I'm only familiar with *valedictorian* (and *salutatorian*) applying to the highest ranked member of a *graduating* class. We would simply have said "top-ranked" or "highest-ranked" until final scores of your final term are completed. The student with the highest grade point at the end of the fall of your junior year is not valedictorian. *Yet*.

Comment: @Random832, Dason: at my school, we had a valedictorian and salutatorian, but a number of students within the top 20 or so were invited to submit graduation speeches, and the administration chose two to be delivered - and (IIRC) neither the valedictorian nor the salutatorian were selected.

Comment: A valedictorian is **by definition** somebody who delivers a speech at the graduation ceremony; in the U.S. that honour by custom goes to the best student in the class. Somebody who graduated at the top of the class in an educational system in which such a custom does not exist cannot strictly speaking be called a valedictorian.

Answer (score 18):

A word more likely to be familiar to British people is *dux*.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/dux) says:

> dux [dʌks] n (Social Science / Education) (in Scottish and certain
>   other schools) the top pupil in a class or school [Latin: leader]

Comment: Never heard that one either!

Comment: _dux_ does not seem really [used in CVs](https://www.google.com/search?q=valedictorian%20cv%20filetype%3apdf). Yet the amount of upvotes is impressive!

Comment: Mmh, Oxford’s definition for _dux_:  “a Saxon chief or leader”. I guess the _(**in Scottish** and certain other schools)_ part mattered  ;)

Comment: I (a Scot) used this word with an Australian colleague who immediately understood. Perhaps common in the Commonwealth?

Comment: As a Brit from South East England, I have *never* heard this. Whereas "valedictorian" I know well, due to watching many US TV shows. (I'd never use "valedictorian" myself though.)

Answer (score 5):

Valedictorian is regularly found in [CVs](https://www.google.com/search?q=valedictorian%20cv%20filetype%3apdf).

Answer (score 3):

In US resumes for law students and lawyers, the person's placement in their law school class is often indicated by the term **Class Standing**, followed by a number looking like a ratio, e.g., 1/340, meaning the student ranked first in a class of 340. Also percentages are used, such as **Top 1%**.

Comment: Or Class Rank: 1/500 (or whatever the rank and class size is). That shows up on our local high school transcripts. Who is #1 can vary from year to year, too.

Answer (score 1):

> **valedictorian**     /væl.ə.dɪktɔ.ri.ən/   /-tɔr.i-/  noun   [ C ] US
>
> a student, usually one who has been the most successful in a particular class, who makes a speech at a special ceremony at the end of a school year
> <sub>[Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=PDHCFSRmjSMC&pg=PA1607&lpg=PA1607&dq=cambridge+%22a+student,+usually+one+who+has+been+the+most+successful+in+a+particular+class%22.)</sub>