# What do you call the best pupil in a class in a single word?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call the best pupil in a class in a single word? The pupil who has the best grades. I need this word NOT to be pejorative, like nerd, geek, teacher's pet, and so on.

Comment: Teacher's pet isn't an insult... not *really*. And now *nerd* and *geek* are badges of honour (especially thanks to The Big Bang Theory show)

Comment: If it were a competition, *first place* or *first seat* or *first chair* would be used. If there were a word for the superlative (best) student in a class, one might be disinclined to use it when there are better-known and better-used ways of expressing the same sentiment. Who would use this word? What problem does the answer to your question solve?

Comment: If this were Dutch Language & Usage, the answer would be “*primus*”. “*Primus*” is simply the Latin word for “first”, but in Dutch is often used as a description for the best pupil in a class, especially if he is male (the female equivalent, “*prima*”, is not used in that context). Most Latin words and expressions used in Dutch are also found in English; but alas! this is an exception. In English, “*primus*” mostly refers to the presiding bishop of the Scottish Episcopal Church, although the longer expression “*primus inter pares*”, “first among equals”, can be used in more diverse situations.

Comment: There are a couple of Google results for the phrase “*primus of the class*”, but they seem to be written by non-native English speakers, mostly of Dutch or Flemish origin.

Comment: In Russian, we use the word *отличник*, *otlichnik*, that has exactly that meaning - an A-grade student, and this sense is non-pejorative.

Comment: Scholar... fits the bill.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to call the best student in a class?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80150/what-to-call-the-best-student-in-a-class)

Answer (score 6):

The best match I can think of is the term "valedictorian."  This word is only appropriate in the context of a graduating class, but it is the closet single word match I can think of.

According to Merriam-Webster the definition of valedictorian is:

[valedictorian](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/valedictorian) - noun - the student who has the highest grades in a graduating class and who gives a speech at graduation ceremonies

Comment: Since “*valedictorian*” comes from Latin “*valedīcere*” (to bid farewell) I would argue that a better definition is: the individual in a graduating class who delivers the farewell (or valedictory) speech, an honour bestowed upon him/her usually on the grounds of him/her being the individual who graduates with the highest grades. Mainly used in the United States and Canada.

Answer (score 2):

Not a single word, but how about, "the star student"?
A "star" in this context is recognized as excelling in the academic sense.  And by using "the" it indicates that it is the one person with that designation.

Comment: "_Top_ student" is an alternative. As Bob says, "_star_ student" means the best pupil also excels at academics. "_Top_ student" simply means the pupil with the highest grades. If the highest-ranked pupil is merely the best of a mediocre bunch, the "top student" would not be considered a "star student".

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on the definition of "the best"...

- The best at extra-curricular activities
- the student exhibiting the best behavior
- the best at sports
- the best because of highest grades

....if the pupil is good at most activities, he/she is an All-rounder.